# MySQL custom auto incremented values

Tags: mysql

I am aware of the auto incremented in MySQL which is based on an integer.

But I need another id as custom generated one auto incremented I'd/current year while the record was inserting.

EG:

```
ID CID
1   1/2017
2 2/2017
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: after insert select max from that column

Comment: Why do you want the id to appear in both columns? This isn't very good database design.

Comment: @kojow, can you please let me know the way to achieve with only CID alone?

Comment: @devanathan check my updated answer below. I provided two solutions for you. The first one is probably preferred, but I do not know your scenario, so the second one would work as well.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you are trying to do, and why you need to do this. So far, it makes little sense to have a derived attribute like this. What is the purpose of CID?

Comment: Do you want the ID in CID to be for that year, so you will get 1/2018, 2/2018?

Comment: @kojow, CId is the customer id with the year attached to it.

Comment: yes exactly i need the same @NigelRen

Answer (score 0):

It is usually bad design to create derivable values in your table data. What about something like this:

```
create table table1 (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    tstamp timestamp default current_timestamp,
    username varchar(32)
);

insert into table1 values (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, "user1");

select id, YEAR(tstamp), username from table1;
```

If you are using a program to retrieve the data, then it is up to that program to display it in a format you like.

But if you prefer to get mysql to generate the display for you, something like this would also work:

```
select id, concat(id, "/", YEAR(tstamp)), username from table1;
```

Comment: it would be tedious if I do the string manipulation each and every time, My application need to do the same for each and every operation I am performing to the record.

Comment: What is tedious about it? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have the application with code first approach and if I doing this I will need to create a mapping for selecting that column.

Also if I need to select the column based on unique identifier I need to split or I need to use both the where caluse.

Comment: Code first approach is a bad idea. Your code should be modeled after your properly developed data structure, not the other way around. Your code should be capable of doing something like this: `SELECT * from table1 where id=1 AND year(tstamp) = 2017`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't need that to happen this customization for each time I query instead I need it as the field in the database. we can remove id if possible.